# How to create a Visual Archive in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I was interested in creating a Visual Archive for a blog somewhat similar to this:

http://www.thisiscolossal.com/visual-archive/

I wanted some input on how I might approach this problem. I am trying to learn PHP and CSS through w3schools, and my plan was to break down this wordpress plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/snazzy-archives/

to see if maybe I can alter it to my liking... I guess my main question is what is the best path to learn how to make this sort of thing?

Thanks for your input!
-Charles

Comment: Are you trying make this for a Wordpress based site?

Comment: Yes, I most certainly am.

Comment: I edited my answer for you. I am actually a Wordpress Developer as well. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start creating HTML Forms and learning PHP's $_GET and $_POST variables.
2. Read the mysql and its functions documentation online from php.net
3. Read about SQL Queries and the ways to execute especially SELECT Query.
4. Also, Try to learn a little of javascript as well. As a little part of it might be required for onclick events.

Edited--

AS per the comments above, like you said, it was for wordpress. I'd say you refer to the Wordpress Documentation as well especially the get_posts() and get_post() functions. You can also lookup for wp_get_attachment_image() for showing just the post images :)

Thats it. Glad to help :D

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much. I'll read all about those functions :)

Comment: Keep practicing. If you need any help. We are there for you :D

Comment: One more question... Do you recommend putting php directly into the archives page or creating a plugin with shortcode? Thanks again!

Comment: The archives page is made by the Theme itself. I'll suggest you to not touch the theme and work on a plugin that works for you. Make a function in PHP that you can call in that archive's page (when your plugin is activated). You can also have a look at add_shortcode() function of Wordpress to add custom Shortcodes and use them directly in your posts as well. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I am working on a specific plugin with a shortcode made in the page. Do you know how I might use get_posts() by date (i.e. month and year)? You've been suuuuuper helpful!

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034697/wordpress-get-posts-by-date-range :)